# how to update a view in viewDidAppear

Tags: objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uistoryboard

I try to create a pseudo-animation, when a view will appear. Here is my code:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {

    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    _image1.hidden = NO;
    sleep(1);
    _label1.hidden = YES;
    sleep(1);
    _image2.hidden = NO;
    sleep(1);
    _label2.hidden = YES;
    sleep(1);
}
```

But the view is not updated before each sleep(). What does I have to add, that the view will be updated after I show or hide a image or label?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
[_image1 performSelector:@selector(setHidden:) withObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:true] afterDelay:1];
[_label1 performSelector:@selector(setHidden:) withObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:false] afterDelay:2];
[_image2 performSelector:@selector(setHidden:) withObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:true] afterDelay:3];
[_label2 performSelector:@selector(setHidden:) withObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:false] afterDelay:4];
```

Comment: A BOOL type is not true/false, it's YES/NO.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `sleep` because it stops your current thread and will prevent your app from updating the display.

I recommend to use...

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5]; // you can also set this to 0.0
[UIView setAnimationDelay:1.0]; // the delay

// your changes which should be animated, example:
_image1.alpha = 0.0;

[UIView commitAnimations];
```

simple and extendable.

Comment: There are better ways to run an animation.  Objective-C is moving heavily towards blocks, so code similar to `[UIView animate...` would be a better alternative.